# Solving $u_t + cu_x = k$ by method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Given the 1st order linear PDE $$u_t + cu_x = k$$ with initial condition $u(x,0)=\mathrm{cosh}2x$, I am required to find a solution using the method of characteristics.

Characteristic equations are 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}s}= 1$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}s} = c$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}s} = k$$

I have calculated, $t=s+c_1, x=cs+c_2, u=ks+c_3$
I'm unsure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to use the initial data, i.e. the values of $u(s)|_{s=0}$:
$$
u(x(s),t(s))|_{s=0}=u(x_0,0)=\cosh(2x_0),
$$
which gives $t(s)=s$, $x(s)=cs+x_0$ and $u(s)=ks+\cosh(2x_0)$. The latter rewrites as
$$
u(x,t)=kt+\cosh(2(x-ct))
$$
by using $s=t$ and $x_0=x-ct$.